# XPATH testing two elements with same attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

given this xml:

```
<illustratedPartsCatalog>
    <figure id="fig1">...</figure>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <figure id="fig2" changeType="delete">...</figure>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <figure id="fig3" changeType="delete">...</figure>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <figure id="fig6">...</figure>
</illustratedPartsCatalog>
```

From `illustratedPartsCatalog` is it possible to write the following XPATH more compactly?

```
<xsl:if test="figure/@changeType='delete' or descendant::*/@changeType='delete'">
```

For example, I've tried many variations of this which fails:

```
*[figure | descendant]/@changeType='delete'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `figure` is a descendant of `illustratedPartsCatalog` you can just write this...

```
<xsl:if test="descendant::*/@changeType='delete'">
```

Or better still, this...

```
<xsl:if test=".//*/@changeType='delete'">
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim, I should have realized that. What if I'm on `catalogSeqNumber` can this be condensed: `<xsl:if test="@changeType='delete' or preceding-sibling::figure[1]/@changeType='delete'">`?

Comment: I think the best you can do for that is `<xsl:if test="(self::*|preceding-sibling::figure[1])/@changeType='delete'">`